# Multiple fifos over SSH

Tags: shell-script, ssh, pipe, file-descriptors, fifo

Shell script allow multiple file descriptors (up to 9 for POSIX compliance, but even more for `bash`):

```
$ install -m 755 /dev/stdin /tmp/test <<\EOF
#!/bin/sh

echo hi1 >&1
echo hi2 >&2
echo hi3 >&3
echo hi4 >&4
EOF
$ /tmp/test 1> /tmp/1 2> /tmp/2 3> /tmp/3 4> /tmp/4
$ cat /tmp/1
hi1
$ cat /tmp/2
hi2
$ cat /tmp/3
hi3
$ cat /tmp/4
hi4
```

I want to achieve the same behaviour over SSH, but what happens is:

```
$ ssh user@remote_machine /tmp/test 1> /tmp/1 2> /tmp/2 3> /tmp/3 4> /tmp/4
$ cat /tmp/1
hi1
$ cat /tmp/2
hi2
/tmp/test: 5: /tmp/test: 3: Bad file descriptor
/tmp/test: 6: /tmp/test: 4: Bad file descriptor
$ cat /tmp/3
$ cat /tmp/4
```

Is it possible to have multiples output pipes over SSH other than `stdout` and `stderr`?

It is important to note I am not looking for port forwarding, since I will have network issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not doable.  The `ssh` client explicitly closes every open file descriptor larger than 2:

```c
/*
 * Discard other fds that are hanging around. These can cause problem
 * with backgrounded ssh processes started by ControlPersist.
 */
closefrom(STDERR_FILENO + 1);
```

This is almost the first thing that happens when the client starts (see `main()` in the source code for OpenSSH 8.0 [available here](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh.c?rev=1.501&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)).